# Getting error CS0031: Constant value `65535' cannot be converted to a `short'

Tags: c#, c++, box2d

I'm getting the above error on this line:

```
Int16 maskBits = 0xFFFF;
```

I am doing this because I am working with the Box2D library, written in C++.
It says [here](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-filtering) that:

> "The default values are 0x0001 for categoryBits and 0xFFFF for maskBits"

I thought 0xFFFF or 65535 was the maximum value for an `Int16`?

Edit: Should be a UInt16  duuh!! thanks people!

Comment: Maybe unsigned, not signed.

Comment: Look in the code examples: `uint16 categoryBits, uint16 maskBits`

Comment: Oh yeah! doh!   (extra text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0xFFFF is for UInt16. For Int16 the max value is 32767.

Answer (score 3):

`0xFFFF` is certainly not a 16 bit signed literal, it is at least (depending on your language: you've tagged a couple) 32 bits with a value 65535. Conversion to a signed 16 bit signed number will fail as the largest value is 32767.

Comment: but not a signed one, unless you add a suffix. And that depends on the language.

Answer (score 1):

the max value of int16 is 32767 which is 0x7FFF

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value for a `int16` would be 32767 as it's signed (the minimum would be -32768)

You want a `uint16` type (as it's unsigned). This would give you a maximum value of 65535 (ie 0xFFFF) and a minimum value of 0.